# Zoom in/out functionality on a custom js code for showing pdf files

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have a custom js code for showing pdf files and here the pdf file is rendered as image. This is a legacy code. The issue is that while zooming in and out, the page number is changed and I want the renderer to stay on the same page while zooming in/out.

```js
 render() {
    return (
      <ReactResizeDetector handleWidth onResize={() => this.handleResize()}>
        <div className='evidence-document-viewer-component vbox hfill vfill overflow-hidden evidence-document-viewer-ez'>

          <style dangerouslySetInnerHTML={this.evidenceStyle} />

          {this.renderDocHeaderContents()}

          <div data-test='ev-doc-scrollable'
            className='ev-doc-scrollable hfill vfill'>

            <div className='ev-doc-inline-contents overflow-auto'
              tabIndex={0}
              ref={this.inlineContentsRef}
              id='mainContainer'>

              {(this.props.noClinicalMessageFound && !this.props.loadedResult?.ezChartAsJson) &&
                <div className='no-document-msg'>
                  ${this.props.noClinicalMessageFound}
                </div>
              }
              {(!this.props.noClinicalMessageFound && this.props.loadedResult?.ezChartAsJson) && this.renderPages()}
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </ReactResizeDetector>);
  }

    renderPages() {

    if (!this.props.loadedResult?.ezChartAsJson?.pages) {
      return null;
    }

    window.setTimeout(() => {
      // for IE support, we will create canvases for all elements on this page if the page image is already loaded
      if (EvidenceDocUtils.useCanvasElements) {
        $('.page-container').each((index, page) => {
          EvidenceToCanvasUtil.createForPage($(page));
        });
      }
    });

    let { pageImagePath } = this.props.loadedResult.ezChartAsJson;
    if (pageImagePath) {
      pageImagePath = `${location.protocol}//${location.host}${pageImagePath}`;
    }

    const pages = this.props.loadedResult.ezChartAsJson.pages;
    const transform = `scale(${this.scaling}) translateX(${this.translateX}px`;
    const zeroPad = (num: number, places: number) => String(num).padStart(places, '0');
    const pageContainerStyle = {
      width: this.contentsWidth,
      height: this.contentsHeight,
      transformOrigin: 'center',
      transform
    };
    return <div className='pages-container' ref={this.pagesContainerRef} style={pageContainerStyle}>
      {pages.map((page, pageIndex) => {
        const pageBounds = this.pageBoundsArray[pageIndex];
        const isVisible = pageIndex >= this.pageIndexToRenderStart && pageIndex <= this.pageIndexToRenderEnd;
        const rotation = this.rotation;
        const style = {
          width: pageBounds.w,
          height: pageBounds.h,
          left: pageBounds.x,
          top: pageBounds.y,
          transform: `rotate(${rotation}deg)`
        };

        return (isVisible && <div
          className='page-container' data-visible={true} key={pageIndex} style={style}>

          <img src="/assets/images/loading_circle128.gif" className='page-image-loading' />
          {!this.suppressPageImages &&
            <img src={`${pageImagePath}${zeroPad(pageIndex, 4)}.jpg`} className='page-image' />
          }

          {page.evidences.map(evidence => {
            // get the index of the evidence in the results
            const conceptIndex = this.evidencesToInstancesMap.get(evidence);
            const key = `${evidence.conceptId}|${conceptIndex}`;
            const { conceptIdsAndInstancesToClassMap } = this;
            const evidenceClassName = (conceptIdsAndInstancesToClassMap[evidence.conceptId] ?? {})[conceptIndex] ?? '';
            if (evidenceClassName) {
              const toolTip = this.toolTipsForConceptIds[evidence.conceptId];
              const style = {
                left: evidence.x,
                top: evidence.y,
                width: evidence.w,
                height: evidence.h
              };
              return <span key={key} className={`nlp cg${evidence.conceptId} ${evidenceClassName}`}
                onClick={this.handleClickEvidence}
                title={toolTip} style={style} data-concept-id={evidence.conceptId} data-concept-index={conceptIndex}></span>;
            } else {
              return null;
            }
          })}

        </div>);
      })}

    </div>;
  }


    @action evidenceZoomIn() {
    this.scaleToFit = false;
    this.scaleToFitPage = false;
    this.evidenceDocScaling *= 1.1;
  }

  @action evidenceZoomOut() {
    this.scaleToFit = false;
    this.scaleToFitPage = false;
    this.evidenceDocScaling *= .9;
  }
```

Currently I am trying to use the transformOrigin property to make sure the focus remains on centre and the page doesn't change while zooming in/out but the issue is that as soon as I use this property the original size of the '.pages-container' element which has all the images rendered inside it gets changed.
Is there anyway I can fix the sizing issue or yet, is there a better way to ensure the page does not change while zooming in/out?

P.S. Please let me know if any further information is required for this question. Thank you!

Comment: Consider your edge cases too: what if it's a 10 page document and I zoom out to show 3 pages on the first page? Centering won't cut it, you need to track the state for "Current page" (last clicked page could work). Another option is to simply zoom at the cursor location, which is pretty common.

Comment: Good point, thanks! But if the user directly clicks on the zoom in/out button which clicking on the image then both the information, including the cursor location will not be available. Then what should I do?

Comment: Just in using chrome's built-in PDF viewer, I can see the behavior they went with seems to be "keep the top position constant, and zoom on that". Speculation, but it's actually the same as zooming on the cursor location, but only if you bound the considered locations for the cursor. In other words, since the zoom buttons are at the top on the chrome viewer, the last cursor location was the topmost coordinate on the document, and that's what could be zoomed on.

Comment: Never be afraid to look at how someone before you has done the same task for inspiration. Many times there's more history, consideration, and effort put behind those public implementations, such that their decisions are actually good ones to make.

Comment: That's helpful I can try that. I have looked for multiple solutions online but none of them fit my requirement. 
Since the codebase I have is legacy, it gets trickier to implement the online solutions.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE: Thanks to Rouge, I was able to get an idea on how to solve this issue. For some reason when I applied 'transformOrigin' directly to '.pages-container' it was creating sizing issue. So instead, I created a hidden point at the center of the main container and applied 'transformOrigin' there.

```
    render() {
    return (
      <ReactResizeDetector handleWidth onResize={() => this.handleResize()}>
        <div className='evidence-document-viewer-component vbox hfill vfill overflow-hidden evidence-document-viewer-ez'>

          <style dangerouslySetInnerHTML={this.evidenceStyle} />

          {this.renderDocHeaderContents()}

          <div data-test='ev-doc-scrollable'
            className='ev-doc-scrollable hfill vfill'
            id='mainContainer'>

            <div className='ev-doc-inline-contents overflow-auto'
              tabIndex={0}
              ref={this.inlineContentsRef}>

              {(this.props.noClinicalMessageFound && !this.props.loadedResult?.ezChartAsJson) &&
                <div className='no-document-msg'>
                  ${this.props.noClinicalMessageFound}
                </div>
              }
              {(!this.props.noClinicalMessageFound && this.props.loadedResult?.ezChartAsJson) && this.renderPages()}
            </div>
            <div
              id="transformPoint"
              style={{
                position: 'absolute',
                left: `${this.inlineContentsRef.current?.clientWidth / 5}px`,
                top: `${this.inlineContentsRef.current?.clientHeight / 1.2}px`,
                transform: 'translate(-50%, -50%)',
                visibility: 'hidden'
              }}
            >
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </ReactResizeDetector>);
  }

    @action handleClickZoomIn() {
    this.props.configuration.evidenceZoomIn();
    this.applyZoom();
  }

  @action handleClickZoomOut() {
    this.props.configuration.evidenceZoomOut();
    this.applyZoom();
  }


    applyZoom() {
    console.log('Inside apply zoom');
    const container = document.getElementById('pagesContainer');
    const zoomPoint = document.getElementById('transformPoint');
    const offsetX = zoomPoint.offsetLeft - container.offsetLeft;
    const offsetY = zoomPoint.offsetTop - container.offsetTop;
    container.style.transformOrigin = `${offsetX}px ${offsetY}px`;
  }
```

This resolved the sizing issue and the zooming in/out feature is a lot better now.